# DFS ends up into an infinite loop

Tags: arrays, algorithm, depth-first-search

I wrote a dfs search for a problem. The problem I am solving is when given an array of numbers (e.g. [2, 1, 3]), I need to iterate through the array and count itself and its neighboring cell if it is filled. So for example, if the array is [2, 1, 3], the answer will be [1, 2, 3]. If the array is [1, 4, 2, 5], then the answer will be [1, 1, 2, 2].

This is what I have:

```py
def solution(queries):
    length = max(queries)+1
    district = [0] * length

    def dfs(spot, district):
        if spot < 0 or spot >= len(district) or district[spot] == 0:
            return 0
        return 1 + dfs(spot-1, district) + dfs(spot+1, district)
    res = []
    for q in queries:
        district[q] = 1
        curr = dfs(q, district)
        res.append(curr)
    return res
```

Somehow my dfs function ends up into an infinite loop. Any suggestion to fix this?

Thanks.

Somehow my dfs function ends up into an infinite loop. Any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I can see there is **no markings for the visited cell** which will allow the DFS algorithm to visit the same cell again and again leading to infinite loop. You just need to mark the cell as visited before you traverse over it. Something like:

```py
def solution(queries):
    length = max(queries)+1
    district = [0] * length

    def dfs(spot, district):
        if spot < 0 or spot >= len(district) or district[spot] == 0:
            return 0
        district[spot] = 0  # <----- Here
        return 1 + dfs(spot-1, district) + dfs(spot+1, district)

    res = []
    for q in queries:
        district[q] = 1
        curr = dfs(q, district)
        res.append(curr)
    return res
```